# error Decoding xml files from .apk file

Tags: android, xml, apk

```
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources:
spec=0x7f030010 layout/abs__screen_action_bar, config=[DEFAULT]
```

I am getting this error when decoding `xml` from `apk file`.
please checkout my Cmd screen below

[image: Cmd Screen]

help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are getting this issue for all the apk files or for particular apk only?

Comment: for this apk only.and i think it is because of duplicate layout files(layout and layout large)

Comment: oh... can you give me the link to download that apk ?

Comment: www.appsapk.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/myHomework.apk

Comment: hi see the answer.. i have just decoded.. fro me its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

for me its decoding correctly.

i have added the reference image . [image]